# Python forms for capturing date & time to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to use a wtf_form in python and flask to have a user enter a date and time and then save it to Sqlalchemy.  I will share what I have, but right now my flask form once populated won't accept the date entries, when I submit the form.  It doesn't give me any errors, so I am sure it is a mismatch.  Any thoughts are much appreciated. Thank you so much for any help.  I am presently using SQLite as my database.

```
class Events(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    eventname = db.Column(db.Text(64))
    eventstart = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    eventstop = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

    def __init__(
        self, eventname, eventstart, eventstop
    ):
        self.eventname = eventname
        self.eventstart = eventstart
        self.eventstop = eventstop
```

My forms.py is:

```
# /myproject/events
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms.fields import DateField


# Building the form in order to get a date picker and save it to the database.
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    eventname = StringField('Event Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    eventstart = DateField(
        'Enter start date and time', id='datepick', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    eventstop = DateField(
        'Enter end date and time', id='datepick', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Register!')
```

My view.py is:

```
from myproject import app, db
from flask import (
    render_template, redirect, url_for, flash,
    Blueprint, request
)
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user
from myproject.models import Events
from myproject.events.forms import RegistrationForm
import validators
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

Bootstrap(app)

events_blueprint = Blueprint(
    'events', __name__,
    template_folder='templates/events'
)

# @login_required
@events_blueprint.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    try:
        form = RegistrationForm()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            event = Events(
                eventname=form.eventname.data,
                eventstart=form.eventstart.data,
                eventstop=form.eventstop.data,
            )

            db.session.add(event)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Thank you for registering your event.")
            return redirect(url_for('list_event'))

        return render_template('add.html', form=form)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Lastly, my HTML is:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}This is an example page{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello, Bootstrap</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <form method="POST">
          {{form.hidden_tag()}}
          {{form.eventname.label}}{{form.eventname()}}<br><br>
          {{form.eventstart.label}}{{form.eventstart()}}<br><br>
          {{form.eventstop.label}}{{form.eventstop()}}<br><br>
          {{form.submit()}}
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  {{ super() }}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#datepick').datetimepicker();
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How do you know it does not accept the date entries when you submit the form, if there is no error?

Comment: Great question.  I will try to insert an if print statement to see if it fails and then understand which field it is failing.  How would you go about trying to find out the error? Thank you!

Comment: In your console/terminal

Comment: I am not getting it to print after the `if form.validate_on_submit():` which means that it isn't validating.  How can I troubleshoot the validation better?  Thank you.

Comment: So, I added `print(form.errors)` after the `form = RegistrationForm()` and the output in terminal is:  ```{}
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Mar/2020 17:57:39] "POST /events/add HTTP/1.1" 200 -```
Does this mean it isn't submitting any data?

Comment: Ok, so I removed the datetime fields and it submitted correctly.  Now, I am going to add them back in.  Is there anything I need to think about as I add in the datetime to get it to submit correctly?  Thank you!

Comment: Try surrounding the register function in the view.py file, with a try-catch block https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp . Let's see if there are any exceptions (remember to print the exception with catch Exception as e: print(e)

Comment: Thank you, Isabi for the suggestion.  I did try to add the try/except but it did not throw any errors.  I updated my view.py code above with the try/except so you can see.

Comment: Have you tried setting the action value of the form? You have <form method="POST" action="My link">

Comment: I will try that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when you're saving the form information into your database. You've correctly declared your event start and event stop as Datetime objects in your models.py and you've also correctly used the DateField input with Flask-WTF so everything is going to look correct on the front end but when you get a date from the form, it comes back as a string and it needs to be parsed and formatted as a date. Luckily there's a way to do that!

Add the following import to your `view.py` file and make these edits for creating the event in your database.

```python
    from datetime import datetime
    ... 

    eventstart=datetime.strptime(form.eventstart.data, '%Y-%m-%d')
    eventstop=datetime.strptime(form.eventstop.data, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

That should fix it! Hope this is helpful.